# Can I name a filtered table within a query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

This might be a stupid question, but....

I have a super simple query that filters a table's contents

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data] 
WHERE 
    Product LIKE 'Repair RepairMate' OR 
    Product LIKE 'Repair TruckEst' OR 
    Product LIKE 'Repair UltraMate' OR 
    Product LIKE 'Repair UltraMate Basic' OR
    Product LIKE 'Repair UltraMate Marine' OR
    Product LIKE 'Repair UltraMate Motorcycle'
```

My question is - can I give this block of data an alias(as t1 for example) so I can easily reference it later in my code? If so how? I know that I could use AS to alias the table it's pulling from but I want to name the filtered output. Thanks

Comment: You mean to create a view from the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE if you are on SQL Server 2005 and later

```
;with c1 as (
  SELECT * 
  FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data] 
  WHERE Product like 'Repair RepairMate' or Product like 'Repair TruckEst'
    or Product like 'Repair UltraMate' 
    or Product like 'Repair UltraMate Basic' 
    or Product like 'Repair UltraMate Marine' 
    or Product like 'Repair UltraMate Motorcycle'
)
select * from c1
```

BTW, you are using LIKE but no wild-card, in this case you can use equal sign or use IN

if so, you can change that long where clause to

```
  ....
  WHERE Product IN ('Repair RepairMate', 'Repair TruckEst',
    'Repair UltraMate', 'Repair UltraMate Basic', 
    'Repair UltraMate Marine', 'Repair UltraMate Motorcycle')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
SELECT [columlist] INTO #yourdesiredname
 FROM .....
```

This will create a temporary table in TempDb. So it will stay until the server is rebooted or you call

```
 DROP TABLE #yoursesiredname
```